# Garbage Collection Setting Solr, sloe performance

Tags: solr, garbage-collection

We use a very old solr 4.2.0 system on OpenJDK6. I am battling a sloooowness issue on our system First I thought it was database, so we tuned all the queries. It did not help. Finally I tracked down to the Solr system performance that is causing the issue. It happens everyday exactly at the same time 8:58am CST, I see a spike in CPU usage and users feel slowness which is significant. And that happens to be the peak usage time with most of the surgeons on the system. I am in the process of migrating our system to a newer platform with Elasticsearch. In the meantime I need to keep this system going. I thought this is related to the GC on Solr. I know this is an age old topic discussed at length. What I see running on the system is the following command, with that what is my heap size, it has two switches Xmx128M and Xmx12500m, which take precedence? My machine has 32GB memory, I can bump this up if necessary. I am not sure where this 12500m is getting set. i looked at the /etc/init.d/tomcat6 script, it is set to 128M there. Not sure where this other setting is getting picked up from? We are on a Ubuntu system in AWS. Thanks for any help.

```
tomcat6  24483 17.3 44.7 19723020 13805172 ?   Sl   Apr13 3597:31 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms10000m -Xmx12500m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: hi, which Full GC or Young GC  is more ？  you need monitor it  and draw a conclusion

Comment: How do I monitor? I have no tools on my system. I have OpenJDK, none of the monitoring tools are installed. How do I install them for OpenJDK6 on Ubuntu? Thanks.

Comment: gcutil is good jdk  tools , for example:     jstat -gcutil  pid    interval   count

jstat -gcutil 16361  200 10